# C++ Error while attempting to iteratively return string

Tags: c++, string, function, iteration

I am attempting to return a reversed version of the string `"Loyce"` in an iterative function. The program runs, but it crashes after running. Any help would be appreciated.

```
string Iterative4(string word)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++)
    {
        if (word.length() - 1 > 0)
        {
            char last_char = word[word.length() - 1];
            word.erase(word.length() - 1);
            string go = Iterative4(word);
            return go;
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    cout << Iterative4("Loyce") << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about `std::reverse`?

Comment: Your `Iterative4` appears to be both iterative *and* recursive. I'm guessing that's not really what you want.

Comment: @JonathanPotter To me, it looks like a homework assignment, where this is the "fourth implementation" of the same problem (reversing a string) in an iterative way. If this is true, `std::reverse` is of course no option (or maybe to be used in one of the implementations they should do).

Comment: I see a few problems: First, what is the outer loop for if you never use `x`? You call your function `Iterative4` recursively, so, probably, you solved problem recursively before and that is an artifact of your changes? Do something with `x` instead. Second, you erase the last character from word, then you don't do anything with it. It will be lost. Since you want to reverse the string, I guess it's not too difficult for you to guess where you should put it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the at function of string. Do not use recursive and iterative together.

```
string Iterative4 ( const string& word )
{
    std::string l_bla;
    bla.reserve(word.size());
    for ( string::size_type x = word.length ( ); x > 0; x-- )
    {

        l_bla += word.at ( x -1 );

    }
    return l_bla;
}
```

this should work, but i didnt test it, maybe you have to change something small

EDIT: Tested now and it works perfectly

Comment: Pass word by const reference.

Comment: Reserve l_bla to word's size.

Comment: Well i think thats a unnecesarry improvement @ this point, but year, i can do it

Comment: It's actually a better improvement than the first one.

Comment: It looks correct to me. The only remaining issue is if the string size is too big for int, but we can live with it.

Comment: unsigned long long should fix this @Neil Kirk

Comment: Or maybe size_t better?

Answer (score 0):

One immediate problem is like that if `word.length() - 1` is not greater than 0, then the function `Iterative4` fails to return a value. Since the function is declared to return a string, this results in undefined behavior, which may include a crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
string Iterative4(string word)
{
    if (word.length() - 1 > 0)
    {
        char last_char = word[word.length() - 1];
        word.erase(word.length() - 1);
        string go = Iterative4(word);
        return go;
    }
    else
        return word;
}

int main() {
    cout << Iterative4("Loyce") << endl;
}
```

I didn't test it.

If you insist on recursion, these or sth like these should work.

As a homework, it's just fine.

But if you are to do some real work, it should be noticed that recursion is a very very expensive action.